# Xcode 5 not installing and running app in simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios7, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5 and running app for iOS 7. When I press "Run" app does not get installed in simulator. If simulator is not running then simulator is started but nothing happens in simulator.
Xcode does not show any error or log. Xcode display status as Running App in Simulator. 
If I quit Simulator still Xcode shows Running App in Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try to select “iOS-Simulator” -> “Reset Content and Settings…” (or similar, I use the German version). Then quit iOS-Simulator, stop the running app in Xcode and then start it again.

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean Project
2. Quit XCode
3. Reset Simulator
4. Exit Simulator before it restarts
5. Reboot Mac

Answer (score 0):

Here is the concrete solution to your problem,

1. launch the iOS Simulator
2. Go and click "iOS Simulator" Menu
3. click "Reset content and settings"
4. close simulator and rebuild your app.

[image]

Above screen shot is showing the way how you can do this...

I think this works for you...!!!